# Avoid that click event for hoverable content triggering event click for parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I have a layout like this:

**html**

```
    <div class="container" onclick="alert('clicked in the container');">
     <img src="notebook.jpg" alt="Notebook" style="width:100%;">
     <div class="content">
       <button type="button" name="button" onclick="action(event, this);">test1</button> <button type="button" name="button" style="float: right;" onclick="action(event, this);">test2</button>
     </div>
   </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
     function action(evt, elem) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       alert('clicked in '+elem.innerText);
     }
   </script>
```

**css**

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px; /* Maximum width */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Center it */
}

.container:hover .content {
  display: block;
}

.container .content {
  position: absolute; /* Position the background text */
  bottom: 0; /* At the bottom. Use top:0 to append it to the top */
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1; /* Grey text */
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  padding: 20px; /* Some padding */
  display: none;
}
```

what I can do for, when I click on any of the button inside the hoverable `.content` div, the event click for the parent element do not being triggered? Right now, when I do that, 2 alerts are displayed, showing the messages "click in test x" followed by "clicked in the container".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop the event propagation (bubbling), hence your parent component will not fire

Altough, you should get rid of prevenDefault you don't need it

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function action(evt, elem) {
           evt.preventDefault();
           evt.stopPropagation();
           evt.stopImmediatePropagation();
           alert('clicked in '+elem.innerText);
         }
</script>
```